# Nominalisierung des Adjektives

Tags: nominalization

Woher kommt die Endung -s (Kriminelles) im folgenden Satz?. Genauer, unter welcher Regel/Kasus wird es formuliert?

> "Jetzt fängst du schon an zu spinnen", sagte er zu sich, nur weil ein Lieferwagen einsam auf einem Parkplatz steht, musst du nicht gleich etwas *Kriminelle**s*** vermuten.

Answer (score 9):

Ein nominalisiertes neutrales Adjektiv wird benutzt, um eine abstrakte, nicht zählbare Sache zu bezeichnen.

> Er hat **viel Schlimmes** durchmachen müssen.
>   Gestern ist **was Interessantes** passiert.
>   Hast du schon **das Neueste** gehört?

Ist das nominalisierte Adjektiv maskulin oder feminin, bezeichnet es dagegen eine Person. Hier finden sich viele Partizipien.

> der/die Alte, Blonde, Neue
>   der/die Wartende, Studierende, Auszubildende
>   der/die Gesuchte, Geliebte, Genesene

Answer (score 5):

Das Verb *vermuten* steht mit einem Akkusativobjekt, das die Gegebenheit darstellt, die vermutet wird.

*Das Kriminelle* ist ein aus dem Adjektiv *kriminell* gebildetes Substantiv. Solche Substantive folgen folgendem Deklinationschema:

> es ist das Neue / etwas Neues
>
> laut des Wichtigen / laut etwas Wichtigem
>
> es dient dem Guten / etwas Gutem
>
> man sieht das Auffällige / etwas Auffälliges

Wie bei den Adjektiven auch gibt es zwei Deklinationsvarianten, je nachdem, ob ein Artikel oder Pronomen bereits die starke Deklination nutzt oder nicht.

Answer (score 2):

-es ist die Endung für Adjektive im Nominativ und Akkusativ Singular Neutrum, starke Flexion.