# Does "Denkendes" refer to someone or something which is thinking?

Tags: meaning

> Überall ist Gedanke und im Gedanken Denken und **Denkendes**, zuerst und zuletzt persönlicher Geist, der selbst in den räumlich-zeitlichen Dingen sich ausdrückt und bet[h]ätigt

Is **Denkendes** referring to some**one** or some**thing** which is thinking?

Comment: Sounds like bloody Heidegger...

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50004/nominalisierung-des-adjektives

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach. Not if it says bethätigt with th.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it can refer to both. Without further qualification "Denkendes" is "that what thinks" and in the quote could refer to some**thing** or some**one**, since the hypothesis is "Überall ist Gedanke" ("Thought is everywhere").

Answer (score 0):

### YES

The verb is *"denken"* (*to think*).

> Ich denke.
>   I think.

The present participle is *"denkend"* (*thinking*).

> Der Professor sitzt denkend am Tisch.
>   The professor sits thinking at the table.

In this form it also can be used as an attribute (i.e. like an adjective).

> Der denkende Professor sitzt am Tisch.
>   The thinking professor sits at the table.

And this attribute can be nominalized, i.e. it is used like a noun when the "original" noun is left. Because it is nominalized, i.e. a noun, it also has to be written with an uppercase letter as first letter.

> Der Denkende sitzt am Tisch.
>   The thinking sits at the table.

And if you use it with an indefinite article, and if it represents something with a neuter gender (e.g. *"das Kind" = "the child"*), then you have:

> Ein Denkendes sitzt am Tisch.
>   A thinking sits at the table.

What is thinking can be a person with a grammatical neuter gender, like "das Kind" = "the child" or "das Mädchen" = "the girl" or "das Männchen" = "the little man" or a thing ("das Gerät" = "the device", "das Elektronengehirn" = "the electronic brain"), as long as its grammatical gender is neuter.

If it was masculine ("der Mann" = "the man", "der Computer" = "the computer"), it would be:

> Ein Denkender sitzt am Tisch.
>   A thinking sits at the table.

And here is the feminine version ("die Frau" = "the woman", "die Maschine" = "the machine"):

> Eine Denkende sitzt am Tisch.
>   A thinking sits at the table.

Btw: I know that nominalized adjectives and participles are rare in English, but they still exist ("the good, the bad and the ugly", "the poor and the rich").

Comment: Ich liebe die Antwort "Ja" auf eine Oder-Frage ;) . Wobei ... in einigen Memes ist das ja heute modern.

Comment: @mtwde: Die Frage war doch: "Bezieht sich "Denkendes" auf jemand oder etwas das denkt?" Und die Antwort darauf lautet nun mal: "Ja, dieses Wort bezieht sich auf jemand oder etwas das denkt." Ich habe diese Frage nicht als Entscheidungsfrage verstanden. Etwas anderes wäre "What does "Denkendes" refer to? To a person or to a thing?" Das wäre eine klare Entscheidungsfrage. Diese Frage wurde aber nicht gestellt.

Comment: Interessant, ich habe die Frage beim Lesen als - wie Du es nennst - Entscheidungsfrage interpretiert, aber natürlich kann man es auch anders verstehen. Wir werden wohl auf eine Klarstellung des Fragestellers warten müssen, bis wir *wissen*, wie es gemeint war...